# adding @angular/material to an angular-cli based project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm new to the all `angular-cli` project creation method, but it seems cool enough to go ahead and test it.

so I created my project with `ng new tuxin-skeleton-angular2-frontend`

it created package.json with the following content:

```
{
  "name": "tuxin-skeleton-angular2-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

so far so good...

just for the fun of it, I ran `npm update --save` but it didn't really update anything because it included specific versions or the usage of `~`.

ok.. now I want to install `@angular/material`. so I simply type `npm install --save @angular/material` and I get the following output:

```
tuxin-skeleton-angular2-frontend@0.0.0 /Users/ufk/Projects/tuxin-skeleton/tuxin-skeleton-angular2-frontend
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.2
├─┬ @angular/material@2.0.0-alpha.9-3
│ └── @types/hammerjs@2.0.33
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.2

npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.0 but none was installed.
```

so what did we learn here...

- `@angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4` requires `@angular/platform-server@2.0.2` and now I have version 2.1.0 installed.
- `@angular/platform-server@2.1.0` requires  `@angular/{core,common,compiler,platform-browser}@2.1.0` while I have version 2.0.2 installed.

so.. in general I have several questions...

1. why did angular-cli installed angular 2.0.0 while 2.1.0 is already out ? is there a way to specify what version to install ? who decides what version should be installed ?
2. is there a way when I try to install `@angular/material`, to let it install the version that is compatible with my current package.json instead of the latest version ?
3. yes.. I can modify each package version manually in package.json, is this the way to go?

since I'm new to `angular-cli` I'm kinda lost on which method to use to move forward.. should I manually patch package.json ? should I downgrade `@angular/material` to the supported version by angular 2.0.2? do I go on a totally different direction? maybe `angular-cli` is not my cup of tea?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Keep in mind angular-cli is still in beta. And there certain scenarios where you can run into troubles with angular 2 itself even it is released. For our case. Update all occurrences in the package.json to 2.1.0 and npm install

Comment: Additional note there is also a new revision of the router which is 3.1.0

Comment: @mh-dev - cool thanks

Comment: In my experience those warnings do not break the builds and are caused because angular-cli is still in beta and their dependencies are out of whack. I would like to know why this is considered acceptable though, surely it could hide bugs and clearly causes confusion.

Comment: @shusson - if there are breaking api changes between package versions then the code will be broken. If it hasn't happened yet doesn't mean it won't happen in the near future. And the errors are related to mismatched packages versions. Angular cli creates package.json and then npm is outputting these errors, not the angular-cli.